# Can I build a golang command-line tool that talks to a localhost appengine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I have a standard appengine + datastore app (not flex) built in golang using these APIs:

```
google.golang.org/appengine
google.golang.org/appengine/datastore
```

I'm trying to write a command-line tool in golang to do various batch things with the datastore, such as migrating data, running consistency checks and so forth. The cli tool uses this API:

```
cloud.google.com/go/datastore
```

I can get the cli tool to talk to my hosted appengine datastore, but I can't figure out how to get it to talk to the localhost dev_appserver.py datastore. The 1st call to datastore `datastoreClient.GetAll(ctx, q, nil)` always hangs.

I read some of the API code, and it looks like I need to set `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` to point to `http://localhost:some_port`, but I can't get this to work w/ any of the 3 servers that are started up by dev_appserver.py (ports 8000, 8080, 53536).

Am I on the right track? I've read a lot of posts & help, but they're either too old, or talk about appengine flex and so forth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the standalone Datastore emulator.

Install it:

```
gcloud components install cloud-datastore-emulator
```

Start the emulator (do this in a background shell, the command runs in the foreground):

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore start
```

And then setup the environment for your application by running:

```
$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)
```

Then run your app, and it should pick up and connect to the Datastore emulator automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get dev_appserver.py to recognize the datastore emulator? Ideally I'd like to get my cli tools & my web app to use the same datastore in localhost for testing.

Comment: There might be a way to connect to the standalone Datastore emulator from your App Engine app directly, ignoring `dev_appserver.py`. Try seeing what environment variables are exposed to the app defined in `app.yaml`, and see if you can change those to point to the standalone Datastore.